# Is time slower on the far galaxies?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity

Since far galaxies move away faster, what would be the speed of their time relative to us?

If there is a difference:

- What determines whose time would be faster?
- (If I haven't understood it wrong) To resolve the twin paradox, acceleration is required. Is the expansion of the universe creates acceleration? If not how can we explain this difference?

I think following question is the same:

Imagine we have a some kind of machine that can bend the space-time, and create a gravitational pull in front of us. So we gain speed without feeling any acceleration. If one of the twin in the twin paradox would use such a machine to gain speed; what would happen?

I don't have a physics or math background, and I hope my question makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

Marco Ocram's answer is essentially correct; I just wanted to give the formula, and back up with some data:

Time runs slower in distant galaxies by a factor $(1+z)$, where $z$ is the observed redshift of the galaxy. This is a prediction of general relativity, and is observationally verified. That is,
$$
\Delta t_\mathrm{here} = (1+z) \Delta t_\mathrm{there}.
$$

This time dilation applies to all physical processes. The figure below (from [Goldhaber et al. 2001](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2001ApJ...558..359G/abstract)) shows how the width supernova lightcurves — i.e. how fast the luminosity increases and decreases — increases as a function of redshift. That is, the more distant the supernova is, the slower it evolves.

The effect is symmetric; an observer in a distant galaxy would see *us* redshifted, and hence time dilated, by the same factor that we see *them* redshifted.

[image: SN]

The redshift is what is observed. To relate that to a distance, one needs a cosmological model. In the standard, flat "[FLRW cosmology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann%E2%80%93Lema%C3%AEtre%E2%80%93Robertson%E2%80%93Walker_metric)", the distance to a galaxy of redshift $z$ is
$$
d = \frac{c}{H_0} \int_0^z \frac{dz'}{\sqrt{
\Omega_\mathrm{m}(1+z)^3 + 
\Omega_\Lambda }},
$$
where $c$ and $H_0$ are the speed of light and Hubble constant, respectively, and $\Omega_\mathrm{m}$ and $\Omega_\Lambda$ are the relative densities of matter and dark energy, respectively.

In the figure below, I plotted the time dilation factor as a function of distance from us. A secondary $x$ axis on top of the plot shows the corresponding lookback time, i.e. how long time ago we see the galaxy; as we approach 13.8 billion light-years — the age of the Universe — time dilation diverges toward infinity. If we could observe all the way back to the Big Bang, processes there would be in extreme slow motion.

[image: time]

Answer (score 1):

Time measured in the frame of a galaxy that is moving relative to us would appear to us to be running slowly. The effect is reciprocal, so our time will appear to be running slowly to observers on the galaxy moving with respect to us. For both sets of observers time ticks away at the same rate in their respective reference frames- there is no difference that needs to be explained. The effect of the acceleration is to increase the relative speed at which the two sets of observers are moving, which will have the effecting of increasing the apparent time dilation effect.

Comment: "The effect of the acceleration is to increase the relative speed" So why we don't say the stationary twin accelerated with respect to the travelling twin in explaining the twin-paradox?

Comment: I'm not criticizing, just trying to understand. Don't get me wrong. But I really couldn't understood this. Both think the other galaxy time ticks slower?

Comment: Imagine you are falling to a no-atmosphere planet, you do not feel any force. Do you have an acceleration then? Or you have an acceleration while staying on the surface of the planet? Or not? I was thinking we have a 10m/sec^2 acceleration on us here on the surface of the Earth.

Comment: It is exactly analogous to the effect of perspective. If you and I stand a long distance apart, I will appear from your perspective to have shrunk. From my perspective it is you that has shrunk. In reality neither of us has changed, but we appear differently to each other. The same is true of time dilation. If we are in motion relative to each other we will each believe that the other's clock is running slow. In fact our clocks continue to record our proper time.

Comment: Acceleration, unlike speed, is absolute, and not relative, so in the twin paradox you cannot consider the stay-at-home twin to have accelerated.

Comment: The first part of this is right, but the last part is wrong. The OP explicitly asks about cosmological expansion, and asks to have it explained in terms of special relativity. This answer seems to claim that this can be done, but it can't. *The effect of the acceleration is to increase the relative speed at which the two sets of observers are moving, which will have the effecting of increasing the apparent time dilation effect.* You don't say what you believe is accelerating, or how you intend to define acceleration. Cosmological Doppler shifts can't be analyzed as SR doppler shifts.

Answer (score 1):

When you talk about farther galaxies moving faster relative to us, you are presumably talking about the effects of the expansion of the Universe.  When you refer to the twin paradox, you are presumably talking about the special relativistic effects of relative motion.  These are not the same thing.  To see this, note that in the first sense, some of those far-away galaxies are receding faster than the speed of light, so if there were time dilation in the second sense, their clocks would be running backward in our frame.

Conclusion:  The question is very hard to make sense of.  The recession of the galaxies certainly does **not** cause time dilation in the "twin paradox" sense that you seem to be thinking of.

Comment: Sir thank you very much for the great answer. I realized how little I know. One question: When we talk about the effects of gravitational pull, i.e. gaining relative speed by the gravity; is it the same thing with respect to expansion of the universe. If it is so, I'm very complicated since the time solves down to zero on the event horizon of a black-hole and the outside observers' time speed up to infinity according to someone falling into the event horizon. Which makes me think special relativistic effects do apply here.